# Use a factory in protractor test

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-factory

After a lot of searching and trying how to use a factory in an e2e test, I decided to finally ask here.

I have a factory defined, with some functions, as follows:

```
regFormApp.factory('myFactory', ['$moment', function($moment) {
        return {
            title: 'Super Title 2014!',
            dates: [
                {
                    date: '2014-10-21',
                    time: '08:30',
                    timezone: 'America/Mexico_City'
                },
                {
                    date: '2014-10-22',
                    time: '08:30',
                    timezone: 'America/Mexico_City'
                }
            ],
            prices: {
                earlyBird: 1250,
                twoMonths: 1375,
                last: 1700
            },
            salesEndDates: function(ticketType) {
                var endDate = this.dates[0].date;
                switch (ticketType) {
                    case 'earlyBird':
                        endDate = '2014-07-19';
                        break;
                    case 'twoMonths':
                        endDate = $moment(endDate)
                                .subtract('months', 2)
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return endDate;
            },
            getSalesPeriod: function(_format) {
                var format = _format || 'YYYY-MM-DD';
                var now = $moment().format(format);
                if (now <= this.salesEndDates('earlyBird')) {
                    return 'earlyBird';
                } else if (now > this.salesEndDates('earlyBird')
                        && now <= this.salesEndDates('twoMonths')) {
                    return 'twoMonths'
                }
                return 'last';
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And I want to use `getSalesPeriod()` in my e2e test with protractor, in order to test if a select is enabled or not.

So, my form looks like this:

```
...
<select id="earlyBirdSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="qty.earlyBird" ng-change="updateTotal()" ng-disabled="disableEarlyBird()">
    <option>1</option>
    ...
</select>

<select id="twoMonthsSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="qty.twoMonths" ng-change="updateTotal()" ng-disabled="disableTwoMonths()">
    <option>1</option>
    ...
</select>

<select id="lastSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="qty.last" ng-change="updateTotal()" ng-disabled="disableLast()">
    <option>1</option>
    ...
</select>
...
```

What is used to enable or disable selects is:

```
regFormControllers.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'myFactory',
    function($scope, $http, $filter, myFactory) {
        ...

        $scope.disableEarlyBird = function() {
            if (myFactory.getSalesPeriod() === 'earlyBird') {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
        // and analogously for twoMonths and last

        ...
     };
}]);
```

So, I want to do something like this:

```
describe('form', function() {


    beforeEach(function() { 
        browser.get('app/#/'); // here is the form
    });


    it('should be enabled only earlyBird select', function() {
        var earlyBirdSelect = element(by.css('#earlybirdSelect'));
        var twoMonthsSelect = element(by.css('#earlybirdSelect'));
        var lastSelect = element(by.css('#earlybirdSelect'));

        // here I want to get 'earlyBird' from getSalesPeriod()
        var period = myFactory.getSalesPeriod(); // it depends to current date
        if (period === 'earlyBird') {
            expect(earlyBirdSelect.getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
            expect(twoMonthsSelect.getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
            expect(lastSelect.getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
        }
    });

});
```

I have no idea how to test it. Any help is very appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy way to do this unless you expose `getSalesPeriod` to the `$scope`, in which case you could do `lastSelect.evaluate('getSalesPeriod()')`

If you don't want to change the app to expose the function you want to call, you'll have to reach into your Angular module by executing JavaScript:

```
browser.executeScript(function() {
  return angular.element(document).injector().get('myFactory').getSalesPeriod();
});
```